# Using Rails.cache in application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am trying initialize my cache in the application.rb so that it gets populated after the initialization of the app

My application.rb looks as:

```
config.cache_store = :memory_store

config.after_initialize do
    Rails.cache.write('key','value)
    puts Rails.cache.read('key')
end
```

`Rails.cache.read('key')` gives an empty value here

but if I put the same code in some other ruby class in rails, it gives the expected output.

Example my_cache.rb

```
    Rails.cache.write('key','value')
    puts Rails.cache.read('key') # gives output value
```

To provide more context, I am also getting this weird behavior my Rails.cache is a `ActiveSupport::Cache::NullStore` in both application.rb and my_cache.rb, where I think it should be a `ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore`

I am using rails 5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Caching is by default disabled in the dev environment.

Therefore I was not able to access the cache.

Running `rake dev:cache` creates an empty `caching-dev.txt` and hence enables caching in the dev environment

This is how development.rb looks like

```
if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.cache_store = :memory_store
  config.public_file_server.headers = {
    'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
  }
else
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
  config.cache_store = :null_store
end
```